# mysql update without real changes on data: does it rebuild index or change data of the table in any way?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, sql-update

Supose that we have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
    col1 int not null,
    col2 int not null,
    col3 int not null,
    primary key (col1)
);
CREATE INDEX myindex ON foobar (col2);

INSERT INTO foobar(col1, col2, col3) VALUES(1, 99, 999);
```

Will an update like this:

```
UPDATE foobar 
SET col2=99    -- same value
WHERE col1=1;
```

perform any kind of modification on the structure of the index? (even if the final structure is the same). Does it also change the value on the table? (even if the value is the same)

Same for an update like this:

```
UPDATE foobar 
    SET col2=99   -- same value
      , col3=444  -- new value
WHERE col1=1;
```

In this case, the col3 gets a new value, but the col2 does not. Will the value of the table and the index structure for col2 be updated?

The question is because we try to know if we can potentially reduce cpu and disk ussage by making finer-grained updates.

Like, for example, chaging previous update to something like this:

```
UPDATE foobar 
    SET col3=444  -- just the new value
WHERE col1=1;
```

Thank you.

Comment: For UPDATE: if there is no real changes then there is no any disk operations. MySQL firstly determines does the data is changed by fact, and only data pages which are really changed are then written. No change in index page - no disk operation.

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer your questions *directly*.  Instead, here are some concepts to redirect your thinking.

`INDEX(col2)` is a B+Tree (see Wikipedia) containing what looks like a 2-column table of `col2, col1`.  That is:  first, the columns of the secondary index, followed by any other columns of the `PRIMARY KEY`.  The tree is sorted by `(col2, col1)`.

The data's B+Tree contains all the table's columns and is ordered by the PK's columns.  Your case is sorted by `(col1)`.  This is unambiguous because the PK is, by definition, Unique.

Given those two points, your question turns into "What happens to a B+Tree when something is modified?".  So...

- Changing the value of `col1` will delete a leaf node in each of the two trees and re-insert the revised row somewhere else (or possibly in the same spot).
- Changing `col2` will modify the data BTree in place (see caveat below).  And it will do the delete + reinsert for the secondary index.

If the length of the a record changes, it cannot be done 'in place'.  (Think VARCHAR instead of INT.)

Another issue:  To achieve ACID in InnoDB, the original value of a modified row is kept until `COMMIT`.  That is, two copies of the row will exist briefly.

Yet another issue:  The BTrees are implemented using "blocks" of 16KB.  Lengthening a varchar in one row might cause the block to overflow.  This leads to a "block split".  Now there is an extra block in the table.  It is *logically* next to its mate, but *physically* it might be somewhere else.  This is where the `+` in `B+Tree` comes in -- the blocks are linked together.

I hope I have given you enough details to answer your questions.